# how to use interfaces with jsdoc?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

```js
/**
 * @param {Object[]} items - Payload should be an array or objects which includes name property
 * @return {String[]} Returns names of all objects in that array
 *
 */

const namesOfItems = (items) => {
  return items.map((item) => item.name)
}
```

I have code like this. It accepts an param named items. Items should be any array of objects like `user`, `car`, `company`, `country` etc. if that object has a `name` property in it. Currently I'm using jsdoc in a project and I setted @param decorator as `@param {Object[]} items` however that declaration is not checking if that Object has a `name` property in it or not. In typescript there were interface's to handle that but I wonder how can I set my @param and show that it only accepts a Object with name property.

Looking for a solution like that below:

`@param {Array<AnObjectWhichHasName>}`

Answer (score 3):

Typescript doesn't support defining interfaces via JSDoc. But you can use an object type in your `@param`:

```
/**
 * @param {{name: string}[]} items
 */
const namesOfItems = (items) => {
  return items.map((item) => item.name)
}
```

Or define the object type with `@typedef` and then use it:

```
/**
 * @typedef {{name: string}} AnObjectWhichHasName
 */

/**
 * @param {AnObjectWhichHasName[]} items
 */
const namesOfItems = (items) => {
  return items.map((item) => item.name)
}
```

Or use this alternative syntax for defining an object type:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} AnObjectWhichHasName
 * @property {string} AnObjectWhichHasName.name
 */

/**
 * @param {AnObjectWhichHasName[]} items
 */
const namesOfItems = (items) => {
  return items.map((item) => item.name)
}
```